# CalDAV in node.js?

Tags: node.js, caldav

Does anyone know of the options for providing a Calendar (CalDAV) interface into a node.js application?

I've seen [jsDAV](https://github.com/mikedeboer/jsdav), but it seems it does not currently support CalDAV.

It seems node+express supports *DAV HTTP methods like PROPFIND, etc, but I doubt it would be feasible to write a CalDAV impl directly as part of my app.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fennel](https://github.com/LordEidi/fennel) is a good start, but it has been archived as of February 2023.

Both CalDAV / CardDAV

Answer (score 4):

Found this: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/caldav seems to be the JavaScript implementation in FirefoxOS so it should work.
It seems to be maintained, comes with unit tests (using Mocha) but no documentation :/

There is a list of libraries on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_CalDAV_and_CardDAV_implementations

Comment: I'm (and most probably others) interested by your feedback since I will probably need this in the future.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is only a client, not a JS implementation of a CalDAV server

Answer (score 4):

At Cozy, we are maintaining this fork of jsDAV which supports CalDAV (server only): https://npmjs.org/package/cozy-jsdav-fork